# Preserving None values in GeoPandas when dissolving (by="id", aggfunc="first", as_index=False)

Tags: python, geometry, geopandas, dissolve, geodataframe

If I dissolve two geometries with the same id and tell to aggregate the other attributes from the first geometry, I get the attributes values from the second geometry because the first is `None`.

Example:

```
id value
1  None
1  2
```

```py
dissolve(by="id", aggfunc="first", as_index=False)
```

Result:

```
id value
1  2
```

Needed Result:

```
id value
1   None
```

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work. Replace the None's with some value that you are sure does not exist, I use -999, dissolve then change them back to None

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np

df = gpd.read_file(r'/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/div.gpkg', layer='diss2')
df['order'] = np.arange(len(df)) #I dont know if fillna can change order, so I save it

df = df.fillna(-999) #Replace None with -999
df = df.sort_values(by='order') #and sort to be sure

df2 = df.dissolve(by='id', aggfunc='first')
df2 = df2.replace(-999, np.nan) #Change them back to None
```